qBittorrent “.unwanted” issue makes script automation impossible. How to work around it?
Coding scripts for qBittorrent is frustrating.
In the latest version, unwanted files in torrents are no longer moved to .unwanted directories for save deleting. This results in external scripts to wait for the download to complete forever since there are lingering unwanted *.!qb files that can't be differentiated from wanted ones.
I can't try to delete every temp file either, since not all temp files are locked. This code used to work for qBittorrent versions up to 4.2.5:
for /f "delims=" %%u in ('dir /ad /s /b .unwanted 2^>nul') do rd /s /q "%%u"

...after which you could simply dir /s *.!qb to reliably realize if the download is complete.
Using the qBittorrent's internal script launcher is not a solution, since it's notoriously unreliable. Correct me if I'm wrong, but not all completions launch the script, which also resulting in downloads to be forever incomplete.
There must be a solution for complete automation other than using an old version qBittorrent client, which makes finding peers/sources difficult, resulting in actually incomplete downloads.
I would love a Batch or PowerShell solution.

Its on linux but - my workflow for qBitorrent involves the internal script launcher, and its worked reliably for years. I fire off a shell script before and after every torrent download, and I've had dozens of successful runs of scripts, with no failures I'm aware of. I need to poke at it a little further, but I also take the approach of storing unfinished downloads seperately which might solve this problem a little more neatly
